# why is it not catching index errror?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def dict_items(dict1):
    try:
        d2={}
        for k in dict1.keys():
            d2[k+1]=dict1[k]+k
            dict1[k]=d2[k]       
    except IndexError:
        print("IndexError")
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
    finally:
        print("Finally done")

try:
    dict_items({1:1,2:22,3:33})
    print("function call done")
except:
    print("Exception")
finally:
    print("inside finally")
```

The above executes correctly and prints

```
Finally done
Exception
inside finally
```

why is not catching index error is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I think It will throw `KeyError` not `IndexError`

Comment: It's a dictionary, you'll get KeyError not IndexError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bare `except:` isn't very useful.  Catch the exception as print its type to see your error:

```
def dict_items(dict1):
    try:
        d2={}
        for k in dict1.keys():
            d2[k+1]=dict1[k]+k
            dict1[k]=d2[k]       
    except IndexError:
        print("IndexError")
    except ValueError:
        print("ValueError")
    finally:
        print("Finally done")

try:
    dict_items({1:1,2:22,3:33})
    print("function call done")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception",type(e))
finally:
    print("inside finally")
```

Output:

```
Finally done
Exception <class 'KeyError'>
inside finally
```

Dictionaries throw `KeyError` not `IndexError` when the key doesn't exist, so the `dict_items` try block catches nothing and prints `Finally done`, then the outer `try` catches the `KeyError` in the bare except.  `Exception` is the base class of most exceptions so you can see what type and value it has, then the final `finally` prints `inside finally`.